# Azure cosmosdb Mongo Api authentication error

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

i am facing a weird issue while connecting to cosmosDb mongoAPi, i have already connected with one database for which it is connecting properly but when i change the credentials of this code with other cosmosdb database, it throws Authentication error

I have already changed '==' in connection string to '%3D%3D'.
Also i have tried using encodeURIComponent

Error given is 
 throw err;
      ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == { MongoError: authentication fail

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var url = 'mongodb://username:password@username.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true';

var listRFID = function(db, callback){
    var cursor = db.collection('rfidDetails').find();
    cursor.each(function(err, doc){
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if(doc != null){
            console.dir(doc);
        }
        else{
            callback();
        }
    });
};

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    var db = client.db(databaseName)
    listRFID(db, function(){
        client.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: This would be a question to ask Microsoft support. Since Cosmos DB is not actually MongoDB and the MongoDB node driver was designed to work with genuine MongoDB servers, it is expected that things don't work as expected.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha thanks for the suggestion, i have already posted there... waiting for their response